# Erro ao listar dados MYSQL via API RESTful com PHP (Ionic 3)

Tags: php, mysql, ionic, array-multidimensional

Bom dia,
Estou com um problema em listar dados no ionic 3 usando o mysql. O problema é o seguinte, tenho um app que lista os comodos de uma casa e o consumo de cada comodo, mas não consigo buscar o id especifico de cada cômodo para que eu possa listar seu consumo.

Era pra listar desse modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue os Códigos (home.ts):

```
public carregarComodos(){
this.Id_usuario = {id: this.id};
this.consumoProvider.getComodos(this.Id_usuario)
.then(data => {
  this.comodo = data;
  console.log(this.comodo.id)

  this.Id_usuario2 = {id: this.comodo.id};
  this.consumoProvider.getAll(this.Id_usuario2)
  .then(data => {
    this.consumo = data;
  });
});
```

**Provider**

```
getAll(id){
return new Promise(resolve => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let option= new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
  this.http.post(this.URL+'/usuarios/select_usuariozinho', JSON.stringify(id))
  .subscribe(data=>{
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

getComodos(id){
return new Promise(resolve => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let option= new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
  this.http.post(this.URL+'/usuarios/select', JSON.stringify(id))
  .subscribe(data=>{
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

**index.php**

```
$app->post('/usuarios/select_usuariozinho', function() use ($app){
 (new \controllers\produto($app))->select_usuariozinho();
});
$app->post('/usuarios/select', function() use ($app){
 (new \controllers\produto($app))->select();
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function select_usuariozinho(){
        global $app; 
        $dados = json_decode($app->request->getBody(), true);
        $dados = (sizeof($dados)==0)? $_POST : $dados;
        $id = $dados["id"];
        $sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM consumo_atual WHERE 
        comodo_id = :id order by id desc limit 1");
        $sth ->bindValue(':id',$id);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $app->render('default.php',["data"=>$result],200); 
    }
public function select(){
        global $app; 
        $dados = json_decode($app->request->getBody(), true);
        $dados = (sizeof($dados)==0)? $_POST : $dados;
        $id = $dados["id"];
        $sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT c.id,c.descricao FROM comodo c  
        WHERE Usuario_id = :id");
        $sth ->bindValue(':id',$id);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $app->render('default.php',["data"=>$result],200); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um JOIN e retornar o consumo já na query dos cômodos. 
 `$sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * from Comodos como INNER JOIN consumo_atual cons ON cons.comodo_id = como.id WHERE como.Usuario_id = :id")`

Nesse momento você vai recebe as informações tanto de consumo quanto do cômodo, ai basta iterar e montar a visualização no APP.

Comment: muito obrigado, realmente funcionou